# Magento 1.9.x Requiring State for Countries Not Set to Require States

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-address

We have added many States, Regions, etc. to many countries in the database. In admin, if we try to edit a customer's address in a country that is clearly not selected in System > Configuration > General > States Options, thus no State is required, Magento still will not allow the address to be changed and saved unless a State is selected. The error, "This is a required field." still appears. Why?

What is the fix?